# Update the Calender Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

Goal:
When I select date for instance 2010-10-22 or 2015-05-15 the calender control will be updated automatically.

Problem:
When I apply this code:

```
DateTime mtDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(150);

-- cdate_left is the name of the calender control in WPF
cdate_left.SelectedDate = mtDateTime;
```

the calender control will not be updated.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Have your tried to add lesser amount of days? Did it work?

Comment: In the end, it was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set both **[`DisplayDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** and [`SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.selecteddate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Properties like this

```
 DateTime mtDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(150);
 cdate_left.DisplayDate = mtDateTime;
 cdate_left.SelectedDate = mtDateTime;
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Calendar is not able to move to such a distant date

Try to change all the associated parameters:

```
DateTime mtDateTime = datetime.now.AddDays(150);

cdate_left.SelectedDate = mtDateTime

DateTime startDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);

cdate_left.DisplayDateStart = startDate ;
cdate_left.DisplayDateEnd = startDate.AddMonths(3);
cdate_left.DisplayDate = mtDateTime;
cdate_left.SelectedDate = mtDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the end of your code:

```
cdate_left.DisplayDate = cdate_left.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

This ensures that the month with the selected date is shown.

Comment: why downvote to this answer?.. This is correct.. your date is selected but it not displayed. +1